# In Linux, how do I uninstall Processing

Tags: ide, upgrade

I use Linux 20 and want to upgrade my Processing programming IDE from Processing 2 to Processing 3. I know how to download and use the .tgz file, but not how to remove the older version

I understand that it is recommended to uninstall Processing 2 first, but how do I go about that, please?